# Git and coordination between programmers in open source/community projects -how does it work?

Tags: git

New to git so please forgive my ignorance.

Assume we have a project with one open source file and two independent programmers decide to change things in that file and this results in two features that are partially conflicting because each programmer modified a certain section of the file to fit his/her needs.

I am assuming that the next step for each of them is to submit a pull request and the owner of the repository will have to resolve the conflicts somehow.

What I don't understand is, in situations when you have large projects (e.g. the Linux kernel) how to they coordinate between these independent contributors? Everybody forking the project and trying to contribute inevitably results in chaos unlike in the case of projects that have coordinated teams of developers led by some kind or overall architect who decides what gets changed by who and when.

Can anybody please explain how this works?

Comment: I do not know how linux handles it (very strictly, with reviewing everything) but in general much chaos can be mitigated by first pulling the most recent version of the master branch, integrating that into your own branch so that it works, and only then create a merge back into master (or a pull request, as you call it in github language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming that the next step for each of them is to submit a pull request and the owner of the repository will have to resolve the conflicts somehow

In case the owner is familiar enough with that code, he could do that. Otherwise he could just accept one of the requests and tell the other guy that he should fix the conflicts - that's the beauty of a distributed VCS. Consider this example:

```
*        (dev1/feature-A)
| *      (dev2/feature-B)
|/
*        (owner/master)
```

`dev1/feature-A` conflicts with `dev2/feature-B`, so the owner cannot merge both branches into his `owner/master`. He decides to merge `dev1/feature-A`:

```
*        (owner/master)
|\
| *      (dev1/feature-A)
|/
| *      (dev2/feature-B)
|/
*
```

Then he tells `dev2` to fix the conflicts. For that, `dev2` for example merges master into his branch:

```
*        (dev2/feature-B)
|\
* |      (owner/master)
|\ \
| * |    (dev1/feature-A)
|/ /
| *
|/
*
```

Now the owner can, for example, use that merge by merging `dev2/feature-B` to `owner/master` as fast-forward:

```
*        (owner/master, dev2/feature-B)
|\
* |
|\ \
| * |    (dev1/feature-A)
|/ /
| *
|/
*
```

[This talk by Linus Torvalds on Git](https://youtu.be/4XpnKHJAok8) might be interesting to you.

Comment: Yes I guess this makes sense, ask the pull request's submitter to correct his code. However if you think about more complex examples where the APIs are changes by the owner shortly before the dev1 and dev2 submit their code ..that may cause problems to both dev1 and dev2. I guess this is the subject of a separate questiuon, there mast be a developement plan (forgot the right term) that lays out the high level future of an open source project

Answer (score 1):

What you said makes sense. The conflicts portion of the code is called merging and it typically happens automatically unless both developers edit the same line of code in the file. If this happens someone manually picks which code gets used.

In larger projects: The main difference (atleast where I work) is we keep a **development branch** in between the individual developers and the master. In other works, no code makes it to master directly, it always goes through the development branch first. Basically adding a layer to the project structure. The project owner/architect is the only person who can move code into master.

```
Master <--(Permission restricted)-- Development Branch <-- Individual developers
```

On larger projects you can have multiple development branches to separate development teams and add layers to this design as needed. If you were to draw a large project, this would look like a big tree.

Hope this helps clarify!

Comment: Also want to note that it is typical to keep a branch separate from master for stable/production releases. This is just another layer to keep potentially insecure/bugged code from making it to the end user.

Comment: Interesting tricks these with a developement branch. I guess the easiest way and the most concludent way would be to look at the history of such complex project or to watch one over time ...Probably the conflicts are not logged in something like Github (I have not looked yet)

Answer (score 1):

"inevitably"?  You're borrowing trouble.  Most merge conflicts are easily resolvable, two people added different meanings for the same new flag bit, so you fix one to use a different bit, things along those lines.

It's truly rare for two people to propose entirely incompatible changes to some source, and in those cases what better tool to have than Git, which lets everybody carry both and discuss possible resolutions?  Sam says let's do it this way, Kim says that way, this is how collaborative problem solving works.